# How to add insert an element after another?

Tags: ffi, purescript

PureScript's `purescript-jquery` package supports this

```haskell
before :: JQuery -> JQuery -> Effect Unit
```

method, which "Inserts an element before another" as shown in its [documentation on pursuit](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-jquery/5.0.0/docs/JQuery#v:before).

Is there a similar function somewhere, which inserts an element *after* another?

I do not see such a method documented on Pursuit. If it does not exist, then how might I implement the same effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have very little experience with PureScript and its FFI, but just looking at the implementation of `before`:

```haskell
foreign import before :: JQuery -> JQuery -> Effect Unit
```

I'm going to take a wild stab at this being what you want:

```haskell
foreign import after :: JQuery -> JQuery -> Effect Unit
```

and then in a corresponding js file for your module:

```javascript
exports.after = function(ob) {
    return function(ob1) {
        return function() {
            ob1.after(ob);
        };
    };
};
```